# problems with configuration of mathjax 3

Tags: mathjax

I have a probem with three options while configuring Mathjax v.3 in my application. The minimal code to reflect the problem is an html file and two js file, one being tex-svg.js downloaded from github and the other being my configuration file for mathjax.
Content of the HTML file reads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_files/mathjax-config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_files/tex-svg.js" async=""></script>
</head>
<body>
first we have $1+\tan(\alpha)^2=\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$, then we have $$\int_a^b f(x,\tau,\epsilon)\,dx$$ and last we would have<br>\begin{align}<br>\sin(x)<br>\end{align}<br>and then continue by going to the next line ...<br>... right here
</body>
</html>
```

and the content of the configuration file is as what follows

```
window.MathJax = {
    options: {
        renderActions: {
            addMenu: [],
            //checkLoading: []
        }
    },
    loader: {
        //load: ['[tex]/tagFormat']
    },
    tex: {
        inlineMath: [ ["$","$"] ],      // ["$","$"],["\$","\$"],["\(","\)"],["\\(","\\)"]
        displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"] ],
        processEscapes: true,           // for \$ to mean a common dollar sign, not a math delimiter

        //ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',    // divs with class "tex2jax_ignore" are NOT to be rendered
        //processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'   // divs with class "tex2jax_process" are to be rendered

        //processEnvironments: true,        // process \begin{xxx}...\end{xxx} outside math mode
        //processRefs: true,                // process \ref{...} outside of math mode

        packages: {'[+]': ['tagFormat','includeHtmlTags','skipTags']},

        skipTags: ["script", "style", "textarea", "pre", "code"],   //their contents won't be scanned for math
        includeHtmlTags: {br: '\n', wbr: '', '#comment': ''},   //  HTML tags that can appear within math

        digits: /^(?:[\d۰-۹]+(?:[,٬'][\d۰-۹]{3})*(?:[\.\/٫][\d۰-۹]*)?|[\.\/٫][\d۰-۹]+)/,    // introduce numbers

        tagSide: "right",
        tagIndent: ".8em",
        multlineWidth: "85%",
        tags: "ams",
        tagFormat: {
            number: function(n){
                return n.replace(/0/g,"۰").replace(/1/g,"۱").replace(/2/g,"۲").replace(/3/g,"۳")
                        .replace(/4/g,"۴").replace(/5/g,"۵").replace(/6/g,"۶").replace(/7/g,"۷")
                        .replace(/8/g,"۸").replace(/9/g,"۹");
            }
        }
    },
    svg: {
        fontCache: 'global',        // or 'local' or 'none'
        mtextInheritFont: true,     // required to correctly render RTL Persian text inside a formula

        scale: 0.97,                // global scaling factor for all expressions
        minScale: 0.6               // smallest scaling factor to use
        //matchFontHeight: true,        // true to match ex-height of surrounding font
        //exFactor: .5,             // default size of ex in em units

        //displayAlign: 'center',       // default for indentalign when set to 'auto'
        //displayIndent: '0'            // default for indentshift when set to 'auto'
    },
    chtml: {
        mtextInheritFont: true,     // required to correctly render RTL Persian text inside a formula

        scale: 0.97,                // global scaling factor for all expressions
        minScale: 0.6               // smallest scaling factor to use
        //matchFontHeight: true,        // true to match ex-height of surrounding font
        //exFactor: .5,             // default size of ex in em units

        //displayAlign: 'center',       // default for indentalign when set to 'auto'
        //displayIndent: '0',           // default for indentshift when set to 'auto'
        //adaptiveCSS: true         // true means only produce CSS that is used in the processed equations
    }
};
```

The problem is with these options:
**skipTags**, **includeHtmlTags**, and **tagFormat**
any of them which I use, an error is written in console which says Invalid option as there is no default value. As far as I have learned, this error shows these are not loaded, but I don't know how to do so. Adding codes like `load: ['[tex]/tagFormat']` gives another error when it cannot find the js file in a specific address, while MathJax3 is seemingly supposed to be a one single file solution.

Where am I wrong? and what's the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the documentation concerning the `skipHtmlTags`, `includeHtmlTags` and a few other options.  They should be in the `options` sub-object, not the `tex` subject.  Also, it is `skipHtmlTags`, not `skipTags`.

As for `tagFormat`, it is not included in the base `tex-sag.js` file, so you do need to load it separately.  Since you have only copied the base `tex-svg.js` file, and no the `tagFormat` component, that will lead to a load failure (the message you are getting).  It would be better if you installed the complete MathJax distribution if you are hosting your own copy, otherwise these kinds of load problems can occur.  Otherwise, you might want to use the `tex-svg-full.js` file, which includes nearly all the TeX extensions.

Here's a working example, using the CDN, and `tex-svg.js`, while loading the `tagFormat` extension by hand (so the initial download is smaller).

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
    options: {
        renderActions: {
            addMenu: []
        },
        skipHtmlTags: ["script", "style", "textarea", "pre", "code"],   //their contents won't be scanned for math
        includeHtmlTags: {br: '\n', wbr: '', '#comment': ''},   //  HTML tags that can appear within math
    },
    loader: {
        load: ['[tex]/tagFormat']
    },
    tex: {
        inlineMath: [ ["$","$"] ],
        displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"] ],
        processEscapes: true,
        packages: {'[+]': ['tagFormat']},
        digits: /^(?:[\d۰-۹]+(?:[,٬'][\d۰-۹]{3})*(?:[\.\/٫][\d۰-۹]*)?|[\.\/٫][\d۰-۹]+)/,    // introduce numbers
        tagSide: "right",
        tagIndent: ".8em",
        multlineWidth: "85%",
        tags: "all",
        tagFormat: {
            number: function(n){
                return String(n)
                        .replace(/0/g,"۰")
                        .replace(/1/g,"۱")
                        .replace(/2/g,"۲")
                        .replace(/3/g,"۳")
                        .replace(/4/g,"۴")
                        .replace(/5/g,"۵")
                        .replace(/6/g,"۶")
                        .replace(/7/g,"۷")
                        .replace(/8/g,"۸")
                        .replace(/9/g,"۹");
            }
        }
    },
    svg: {
        fontCache: 'global',        // or 'local' or 'none'
        mtextInheritFont: true,     // required to correctly render RTL Persian text inside a formula
        scale: 0.97,                // global scaling factor for all expressions
        minScale: 0.6               // smallest scaling factor to use
    }
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async
   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>

Testing math:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2<br>
+1}
\end{align}
```

I've left in the `skipHtmlTags` and `includeHtmlTags` options, even though these are the defaults and they could be removed.  Also, the `tagFormat.number` function receives a *number* not a string, so you need to create the string from it before you can do the substitutions.

Finally, this example has pointed out that there is a timing issue between the `tagFormat` extension and the `ams` tag format (which isn't available until after the `ams` extension is registered), so I've used the `all` tagging for now.  I will submit a bug report for that.

---

**Edit**

Here's a version that includes a patch that overrides the `tagFormat` extension with one that handles the `ams` tags properly.  You can use it for now until MathJax is fixed.

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
    loader: {
        load: ['[tex]/tagFormat']
    },
    startup: {
      ready: function () {
        var Configuration = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration.Configuration;
        var TagsFactory = MathJax._.input.tex.Tags.TagsFactory;
        var tagFormatConfig = MathJax._.input.tex.tag_format.TagFormatConfiguration.tagFormatConfig;
        var TagformatConfiguration = MathJax._.input.tex.tag_format.TagFormatConfiguration.TagformatConfiguration;
        Configuration.create('tagFormat', {
          config: function (config, jax) {
            var tags = jax.parseOptions.options.tags;
            if (tags !== 'base' && config.tags.hasOwnProperty(tags)) {
              TagsFactory.add(tags, config.tags[tags]);
            }
            return tagFormatConfig(config, jax);
          },
          configPriority: 5,
          options: TagformatConfiguration.options
        });
        return MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      }
    },
    tex: {
        packages: {'[+]': ['tagFormat']},
        tags: "ams",
        tagFormat: {
            number: function(n){
                return String(n)
                        .replace(/0/g,"۰")
                        .replace(/1/g,"۱")
                        .replace(/2/g,"۲")
                        .replace(/3/g,"۳")
                        .replace(/4/g,"۴")
                        .replace(/5/g,"۵")
                        .replace(/6/g,"۶")
                        .replace(/7/g,"۷")
                        .replace(/8/g,"۸")
                        .replace(/9/g,"۹");
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>

Testing math:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2<br>
+1}\qquad \text{with AMS number}
\end{align}

$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}\qquad\text{with no number}
$$
```

I've removed the options that don't play a role in this in order to make this example a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration, but copying your modified configuration code into my config file, and calling for `tex-svg-full.js` by `<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg-full.js"></script>`, yet not `<br>` in the equation is skipped and not tagFormat get to work. Can you please add a working snippet or direct me to a working example?

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works fine. Only one thing, if in my code I have `<br>\begin{align}...` it throw the error message `Q.splitText is not a function`, while if I only put a blank space like in `<br> \begin{align}...` the error is resolved and the math is typesetted as is in your example. Maybe it's a bug, or I cannot see the point behind it? All in all. great answer as always, thank you again

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug.  I will file a bug for that, as well.

Comment: @owari, I have added another example that includes a patch to allow `tagFormat` to work with `ams` tags.  It includes a dollar-delisted expression in order to show that it is using AMS numbering, not numbering *all* expressions, as in the previous example.